# How can I stop moving the hyperlinks to new line UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am facing a minor trouble with `UITextView`. I am having a `UITextView` which detects everything. When there is no space to fit the hyperlink, it moves that to new line.

[image]

How can I stop it? I want to have the hyperlink to be on the same line as long as it fits like below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works
Select TextView text Attributed and line breaking mode to character wrap

[image]

Output:
[image]

Hope this will help you.
Thanks.

Comment: How can I do it programmatically?